# Create inner-class object after executing outer-class's constructor in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, constructor, inner-classes

I want to create objects for inner classes in a class. All the inner class methods use a common variables which needs to be initialised when the the outer class is created.

```
class A
    @x = nil
    @y = nil
    def initialize(x, y)
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end

    class B
        def func_b
            puts "x- #{@x} and y- #{@y} in class B"
        end
    end

    class C
        def func_c
            puts "x- #{@x} and y- #{@y} in class C"
        end
    end
end
```

I was able to create object for classes `B` and `C` like

```
#1
b = A::B.new
#2
a = A
c = a::C.new
```

But I want to initialize `A` before creating objects for `B` or `C`

Something like

```
a = A.new(4,5)
b = a::C.new
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How should I do the above.

Answer (score 2):

Nested modules and classes in Ruby are a mostly organizational choice. Compare this

```
class A; end
class B; end
```

and this

```
class A
  class B; end
end
```

There are only two differences between these

1. In the second example, you have to write `A::B` to access `B`
2. In the second example, constants accessed in `B` will be looked up in `A` before they are looked up in the top-level

If you actually want the *instances* of these classes to be related, you need a sub- and superclass relationship between them i.e.

```
class B < A; end
```

now instances of `B` can access methods and instance variables in `A`. Note that this is independent of nesting, you could define that as

```
class A
  class B < A; end
end
```

but again that's only an organizational difference.

---

On a totally separate note, this

```
class A
  @x = nil
  @y = nil
end
```

does **not** do what you think it does. This is setting instance variables on `A` itself, i.e. treating `A` as an instance of `A.singleton_class`. If you want default values for the *instances* of `A`, you have to set those in `initialize`:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @x = nil
    @y = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
    def initialize(x, y)
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
end

class B < A
    def func_b
        puts "x- #{@x} and y- #{@y} in class B"
    end
end

class C < A
    def func_c
        puts "x- #{@x} and y- #{@y} in class C"
    end
end

c = C.new(4,5)
c.func_c
```

prints

```
x- 4 and y- 5 in class C
```

This seems to work fine :).

Comment: This "solution" has nothing to do with what you asked... you should do some more reading on OOP, because it seems like you don't know the right language to express these concepts.